Field mapping problem in SAP Service Cloud third-party communication
I use the browser post message method to send XML payloads to the SAP according to this:
SAP Library > Phone Events and Payload.
Do you know how to pass the data to the "Notes" field? So far, I haven't been able to find a way to map data in this field, so any hints on where I could search for more information about this would be very appreciated.

I just found a video that confirms it's possible to pass it:
https://youtu.be/t6wtw95xs-I?si=OOZ7SiM083wllTVf&t=129
I tried using different names for that field, none of them worked and I can't find any information in the documentation that would help me learn what is the key for this field.
